# Laravel maintenance mode on specific subdomain

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-middleware

I know that you can except some URIs of your main app like if you want to except `example.com/page`, you can just simply add it to the `CheckForMaintenanceMode.php`, like this:

In `app/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode as Middleware;

class CheckForMaintenanceMode extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be reachable while maintenance mode is enabled.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/page'
    ];
}
```

Now, my app has a couple subdomains using one app; I have a subdomain for my main app: `app.example.com`, a subdomain for my API endpoints: `api.example.com` and the main website: `www.example.com`

How can I possibly `except` the specific subdomain instead of URI for maintenance mode? Like having `api.example.com` and `app.example.com` in maintenance mode but not the main website `www.example.com`?

I'm trying to figure out it on my own and even make my own middleware just to do this, but is it possible to do this using the built-in maintenance mode of laravel with `php artisan:down`?

Something like:

```
// app.example.com and api.example.com is in maintenance mode except:

protected $except = [
    'example.com'
    'www.example.com'
];
```

Comment: cant you just add `'www.example.com/*'` to the except array?

Comment: @Flame I did that, it doesn't work. I guess that the `$except` object is only meant for URIs

Comment: Investigate the `CheckForMaintenanceMode` class, it calls a `$request->fullUrlIs($except)` function. I havent tested its inner workings but I think it should work with the full url. You obviously have to test this in such way that youre not using `http://localhost` in your browser.

Comment: @Flame It actually works with protocol. Please add it to the answer so I can accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckMaintenanceMode` middleware class:

It checks the elements of the `$except` property using the function `fullUrlIs()` from the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class, which itself calls the `Str::is()` helper (also known as the `str_is()` function if you're using Laravel helper function globals):

```php
protected function inExceptArray($request)
    {
        foreach ($this->except as $except) {
            if ($except !== '/') {
                $except = trim($except, '/');
            }

            if ($request->fullUrlIs($except) || $request->is($except)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-str-is

You should then be able to check for an url like this, to exclude this domain from the maintenance mode (i.e. it will always be up):

```php
protected $except = [
    'https://www.example.com/*'
];
```

Comment: You also have to include both `https://www.example.com/` and `https://www.example.com/*` so the main URL and its paths become accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two domains. One is the main domain
and another one is a subdomain.

- mydomain.com
- admin.mydomain.com

You have a page name maintenance. The maintenance page is under the main domain. The URL of the maintenance page is mydomain.com/maintenance.
In the maintenance mode, you will have the route permission of  mydomain.com/maintenance and admin.mydomain.com

Now work process.
Goto App\Http\Middleware the open the PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance  middleware then add this code

```
protected $except = [
   'maintenance*',
   'http://admin.*',
   'https://admin.*'
];
```

Then go to App\Exceptions open Handler file, inside render function add

```
if (App::isDownForMaintenance()) {
   return redirect('/maintenance');
}
```

Now run `php artisan down`